# Executable misses some libraries (but present on system), how to install/link them?

Tags: linux

I have the problem, that it seems that not all required libraries are found. Please see the output below. It seems however that they are installed on my system. What would I have to do next? (I am sorry, I do not have a good knowledge about linux. Is this only a problem of setting somewhere some symbolink links, or is this a problem of 32 vs 64 bit libraries? What can I do to fix the problem?

```
static:/usr/local/openemm/bin# ldd xmlback
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7f29000)
        libxml2.so.2 => not found
        libz.so.1 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7efd000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf7ef9000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7da6000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f2a000)

static:/usr/local/openemm/bin# find / -name libz*
/usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
/usr/lib/libz.so.1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.12/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
/usr/lib/libz.so
/usr/lib/libz.a

static:/usr/local/openemm/bin# find / -name libxml2*
/usr/include/libxml2
/usr/lib/libxml2.so
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.6.32
/usr/lib/libxml2.la
/usr/lib/libxml2.a
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.6.32

uname -a ==> SMP Sat Jan 10 17:57:00 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you very much!!!
Jens

**UPDATE:** (thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and Warner)

```
    file -s /usr/lib/libz.so.1
    /usr/lib/libz.so.1: symbolic link to `libz.so.1.2.3.3'

    file -s /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

static:/usr/local/openemm/bin# file -s /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.6.32
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.6.32: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped


      file -s xmlback
    xmlback: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

==>Seems to be a 32 vs 64 Conflict. I would be very thankfull for advice what I could do here in case the xmlback is a file that was distributed with the application I want to install (openemm.org).So I asume I can not replace this file. But maybe there is a solution to use 32 bit libraries or some kind of wrapper?? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ldconfig` as root.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I did run "ldconfig", but running "ldd xmlback" still prints out,that the libraries are missing. Would there be something else I can do (Or do I have to reboot)? Thank you very much!

Comment: `/sbin/ldconfig` with no flags or parameters.

Comment: If the libraries still show as missing then run `file` against them to verify that they're the correct arch and endianness.

Comment: Hello Ignacio, thanks for your great help!! 
The problem seems to be caused by a version conflict 32 vs 64. (I updated the post above with the output). If you also know any advice what I could do here would be absolutely great. thanks!

Comment: At this point you have to install the 32-bit versions of libxml2 and zlib. I'm not sure how Debian/Ubuntu does multilib, so you'll need to find further direction elsewhere.

Comment: Ignacio, thanks very much for your help, have a nice weekend!!!